# nested if in 2 or more fields

Tags: java, oracle-sqldeveloper, ibatis

I'm trying to do something like this on ibatis :

```
<isNotEmpty property="propertyA">
    <isNotEmpty property="propertyB">
        query regarding propertyA and propertyB                         
    </isNotEmpty>
    <isEmpty property="propertyB">
        query regarding propertyA ONLY!!!               
    </isNotEmpty>                   
</isNotEmpty>

<isEmpty property="propertyA">
    <isNotEmpty property="propertyB">
        query regarding propertyB ONLY!!!                               
    </isNotEmpty>
</isEmpty>
```

but my code doesen't work. how can i do this? thanks in advance...

Comment: Do you get an error message?

Comment: I solved creating a field propertyC, and setting the propertyC(on java side) to "Y" when propertyA AND propertyB are both != null AND != "". Then on ibatis side i do the proper query. Thanks anyway :)